# TP Link TL-WR841N - sun light/symbol meaning?

Tags: router

I'm asking this out of pure curiosity.

Could you explain what the "sun" symbol/light on the router means - not all of them have it, it seems - for example the one (the exact same model number) on TP Link's website doesn't have it and thus is not explained anywhere in the manuals (including my manual), but my router and the one sold on amazon has: [http://www.amazon.com/TP-LINK-Wireless-300Mbps-Certified-TL-WR841N/dp/B001FWYGJS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FWYGJS)

The symbol is the second one from the left, between the power symbol and the one for the wifi. It seems to always blink at a constant rate regardless of whether the wifi works or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That light is a "system" indicator, basically a heartbeat that should flash during normal operation. If its not flashing, the router is experiencing some sort of CPU issue.  It's not super useful, so it was dropped from later versions.  Here is a manual that includes the info: https://www.a1m.cz/public/files/documents/aim-manual841n-2012.pdf

Comment: Please edit your answer, the link you provided in your answer is broken.

Comment: Edited with new link